# when i tries to search a keyword in a json document in "sense" elastic search it is as follows

Tags: elasticsearch

I have inserted as follows:

```
PUT /megacorp/employee/5
{
    "emp1":{
    "first_name" :  "Douglas13",
    "last_name" :   "Fir13",
    "age" :         3513,
    "about":        "I like to build cabinets13",
    "interests":  [ "forestry13" ]
    },
    "emp2":{
     "first_name1" :  "Douglas23",
    "last_name1" :   "Fir23",
    "age1" :         3523,
    "about1":        "I like to build cabinets23",
    "interests1":  [ "forestry23" ]
    }
}
```

I want to retrieve the whole document when i search with "age=3513" and "age1=3523".

```
GET /megacorp/employee/_search
{
    "query" : {
        "match_phrase" : {
            "age" : 3513
        }
    }
}
```

The document is not retrieved for this query.

while for "age=3523" i have written the same query as below and the doc is retrieved .

```
GET /megacorp/employee/_search 
{
    "query" : {
        "match_phrase" : {
            "age1" : 3523
        }
    }
}
```

Someone please clarify why the document is not retrieved with "age=3513".Thank you

Comment: Could you show the mapping?

Comment: I am getting results in both the cases.

Comment: Are you really indexing **two employees** (`emp1` and `emp2`) inside a single document of your `employee` type? Shouldn't these be two different documents? Or are they the same employee indexed in two different ways?

Comment: Hello Atri , can you tell me what do you mean bye mapping?

Comment: Richa, i am not getting result. i am tring it in sense . Can you tell me how did you try?

Comment: hello val, i want to store two employees in an id 5, i am not able to retrieve the result ,i am trying it in sense. Can you please suggest me ?

Comment: Have you tried using a `term` query?

Comment: Hello Brooke , yes i tried with term query too. I am not able to get the result

Comment: I am actually working on large number of JSON files ,  a single json file consists of many "section_details" as subsections in it. i am not able to get the search result in the "section_details" subsections while i am able to get in all other subsections. so, i tried a similar small JSON file as above.But i am not able to get the result. i am still in search of an answer. If anyone want to try that let me know, i will post a original JSON  document that i am facing problem.

Comment: I am not able to retrieve the document because i didn't give any mapping to elastic search. As it is taken default mapping, in some cases we can't retrieve the required results. Before indexing a document , mapping is important .

Answer (score 1):

I am not able to retrieve the document because i didn't give any mapping to elastic search. As it is taken default mapping, in some cases we can't retrieve the required results. Before indexing a document , mapping is important